# Gateway interface breaking after upgrading from SI v 2.2 to v 3.0.5

Tags: spring-integration, spelevaluationexception

After upgrading SI from v 2.2 to v 3.0.5 I'm getting an error for the following gateway. Has the behaviour of gateway interfaces changed in v 3.x to not accept Message types?? Any hints would be appreciated as to why this is happening.

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method sendStat(my.domain.ReplyStatEvent) cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22 type]

```
void sendStat(@Payload Message<? extends LiveStatEvent> message);
```

ReplyStatEvent extends LiveStatEvent and the gateway is invoked using a service activator definition like this:

```
<int:service-activator ref="liveStatsGateway" method="sendStat" />
```

It works fine after changing the interface to the following.

```
void sendStat(@Payload LiveStatEvent message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it had worked before, it doesn't mean that it was correct syntax.

If your gateway's param is marked with `@Payload`, it is assumed that Framework will inject to that arg a `payload` of the `Message`, but not entire `Message`.

We just fixed that ambiguity and show you now that your use-case isn't correct.

So, if you want to use just `payload`, you'll be able to specigy just payload type for param.
The `@Payload` isn't necessary is this case. It is required, if your method has several args and Framewrok can't determine which one for payload.

If you want get deal with whole `Message`, there is just enough to have an arg of that type.

Anyway a combination `@Payload Message<?>` isn't correct. Hence you just need to fix those [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki) cases.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Seems kind of obvious now that you say that. I've no idea why that was annotated as @Payload.